# RESTFul Architecture getting request from another domain

Tags: php, rest, cross-domain

I have a server in which I have a REST API together with a front end that interact with that API.

As long as the front end is on the same server as the REST API, the application works, but when i move the front end to a different server , it stops working!!

The whole application interact with the REST API for all operations.

Is there a mean to make the front end interact with the REST API provided both are on different domain??

When the front-end that interact with the REST API is on the same domain, the front-end works, but when it is on a different domain, it doesn't!!

Comment: Can you provide details about what you're trying to do and what "doesn't work"?

Comment: It is somewhat intentional that you can only send requests to your own domain.

Comment: what about web service, normally, request from other domain can also come

Answer (score 1):

Browser will block requests to a different site to prevent XSS attacks. Your rest server should tell the browser requests from which sites requests are allowed to get around this. There are two ways of doing this, through a crossdomain.xml file and through the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header.

Unfortunately browser support for those solutions is lacking in older browsers, so you should check which browsers you want to support.